# How to use the `maxspeed` key in openstreetmap?

Tags: performance, gps, openstreetmap

Can we retrieve the maximum allowed speed (approx.) on a road using maxspeed key?

Provide if any codes available with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the OSM wiki on the [maxspeed](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed) tag:

> The maxspeed=* tag is used to define the maximum legal speed limit for
>   general traffic on a particular road, railway or waterway. By default,
>   values will be interpreted as kilometres per hour. If the speed limit
>   should be specified in a different unit the unit can be added to the
>   end of the value, separated by a space.

So yes, it specifies the maximum allowed speed on that road.